Disk Capacity and Usage in TDP_DiskDrive Class in HPE 3PAR
I want to read disk capacity and usage via CIM classes including TPD_DiskDrive. I can find the following properties according to HPE 3PAR API Reference:
[Description ("Size of the chunk.") ]
uint64 ChunkSize;
[Description ("Number of Normal Used OK chunks.") ]
uint32 ChunksNormalUsedOK;
[Description ("Number of Normal Used Fail chunks.") ]
uint32 ChunksNormalUsedFail;
[Description ("Number of Normal Unused Free chunks.") ]
uint32 ChunksNormalUnusedFree;
[Description ("Number of Normal Unused Uninitialized chunks.") ]
uint32 ChunksNormalUnusedUninit;
[Description ("Number of Normal Unused Fail chunks.") ]
uint32 ChunksNormalUnusedFail;
[Description ("Number of Spare Used OK chunks.") ]
uint32 ChunksSpareUsedOK;
[Description ("Number of Spare Used Fail chunks.") ]

uint32 ChunksSpareUsedFail;
[Description ("Number of Spare Unused Free chunks.") ]
uint32 ChunksSpareUnusedFree;
[Description ("Number of Spare Unused Uninitialized chunks.") ]
uint32 ChunksSpareUnusedUninit;
[Description ("Number of Spare Unused Fail chunks.") ]
uint32 ChunksSpareUnusedFail;

I read the total capacity using MaxMediaSize property inherited from the parent class, CIM_DiskDrive. But in one of my disks I have ChunksNormalUsedOK=~3500 and ChunkSize=1073741824B=1GB while MaxMediaSize =~3000GB and the disk is working normally. How is this possible?

Am I reading the proper value for disk capacity?

Can I sum up the chunk numbers and multiply it by chunksize to get the total disk capacity?


